# Get All index locations for specific month/day for all years

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas PeriodIndex of

```
x = pd.PeriodIndex(start='1/1/2000', end='12/31/2010', freq='d')
```

How can I select all dates with in a month for all years

```
#ppMonth is a pandas Period, 
#randomNum is a random day within that month

indexLoc = x.get_loc(str(ppMonth.month) + "/" + str(randomNum) + "/" + str(ppMonth.year))
```

This is terrible and inefficient and only gets what is in that specific year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `month`

```
x[x.month==10]
Out[455]: 
PeriodIndex(['2000-10-01', '2000-10-02', '2000-10-03', '2000-10-04',
             '2000-10-05', '2000-10-06', '2000-10-07', '2000-10-08',
             '2000-10-09', '2000-10-10',
             ...
             '2010-10-22', '2010-10-23', '2010-10-24', '2010-10-25',
             '2010-10-26', '2010-10-27', '2010-10-28', '2010-10-29',
             '2010-10-30', '2010-10-31'],
            dtype='period[D]', length=341, freq='D')
```

Comment: is there a way to exclude the first 3 days and last 3 days? - I'll except this as the answer in 5 minutes per SO

Comment: @Sorceri you mean the last there day of the month ?

Comment: Correct so in your example using October,   10/4 to 10/28

Comment: @Sorceri `x[(x.month==10)&(x.day>=4)&(x.day<=28)]
`